# Sendmail consumer for AMQP

Tags: email, rabbitmq, sendmail, amqp

I am looking for a light weight and robust AMQP consumer for sending emails using sendmail. Dose anything like this exists or do I have to write something on my own?

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to write your own. The closest thing I've seen is a [plugin to receive SMTP in [RabbitMQ](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-smtp) which is definitely not what you want.

A general solution for this can become rather complex managing idempotency of the messages. In previous solutions to this problem I passed a unique ID in the message and use a persistent store to handle deduplication. After successfully handing off the email the ID is written. Depending on how sure you want to be about ensuring hand-off / preventing duplication you can add more of a lock.

Answer (score 0):

[MailerQ](http://www.mailerq.com/) could be similar to what you are looking for. However, it uses it's own SMTP server, and not sendmail.

I'm also looking for some consumer application that can receive RabbitMQ messages and send them as emails. However, I need it to use an external SMTP server, so MailerQ is not right for me.